# Use tomcat webapp as the root path for apache/mod-jk virtualhost

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-jk, tomcat9

I have configured a server where lies several domains, and more than one of them have a ajp13-worker associated to it. The configuration file looks like that:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin my@email
        ServerName mydomain
        ServerAlias www.domain
        DocumentRoot /home/kleber/www/loja
        JkMount /app* ajp13_worker
        ...
</VirtualHost>
```

when I deploy some webapps like `appOne.war` and `appTwo.war` to my tomcat webapps directory, I can access them using something like that: `https://mydomain/appOne` and `https://mydomain/appTwo`.

How I could configure the `mod-jk` plugin with the `tomcat` and `apache` to allow me access some of this webapps as `https://mydomain/` only? In a way I could define one webapp per domain using the `mod-jk` ajp13-worker to be the root path, and allowing me continuing to access the webapps `appOne.war` and `appTwo.war` as before.

**update**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin ...
        ServerName ...
        ServerAlias ...
        DocumentRoot /home/kleber/www/loja
        JkMount /app* ajp13_worker

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =... [OR]
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =...
        RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: A simple rewrite to the desired application URL should do the trick.

Comment: do you can give me a hint of how to do that? also, is it possible do that without any redirection? I already have on configured by the certbot application.

Comment: That's an internal rewrite.  https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html

Answer (score 0):

You need an internal rewrite:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin my@email
    ServerName loja-de-software.net.br
    ServerAlias www.loja-de-software.net.br
    DocumentRoot /home/kleber/www/loja
    JkMount /app* ajp13_worker

    RewriteEngine  on

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} loja-de-software.net.br
    RewriteRule /(.*) /appOne/$1 [PT,END]

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Is there a problem use 2 RewriteRules for the same VirtualHost? Like shown in the update in the question, I already have one, inserte there by the certbot/let's encrypt tool. Can I add another without cause any issues?

Comment: Yes, there is a problem.  The rule you have catches every request for two domains and ends the rewriting.

Comment: Is there any workaround for that? Or any solution not involving redirect?

Comment: Sure, and I'd like to repeat that there is no redirecting in the new rule.  See edited answer.

Comment: The rule added by the "certbot" does send a redirect to HTTPS.  This configuration doesn't catch port 443.

Comment: I finally tried this solution, but when I add this lines to my virtualhost configuration file, I am not able to start apache, due error on this lines. 2 questions: 1) `appOnedomain` should be the complete domain name, with the app name (`loja-de-software.net.br/appHello`) or something else? and 2) if I define this `JkMount /app* ajp13_worker` do i should use `/app*` or `/appHello` in the redirect rule?

Comment: Edited my answer, "=domain", not "= domain" in the RewriteCond. "/app*" may be OK for JkMount, but probably not in a rewriterule. "/app.*" maybe?

Comment: Edited once more, probably the END flag is needed too.

Comment: But instead of `appOnedoman`  and `appTwodomain` I should use the full domain name (` loja-de-software.net.br` ) or the name of the webapp (for instance `appHello` or something)?

Comment: If you had to answer that yourself, what would it be?

Comment: I've added the two domains to the ServerAlias directive, otherwise the RewriteCond's made no sense.  Once more: why the redirect to https?  What happens with the https requests?

Comment: I not access the webapps using a subdomain (something like `appOnedomain.mydomain.com`). I have one ServerAlias configured, to allow access to `www.loja-de-software.net.br` and `loja-de-software.net.br`. I do not create a new alias for each webapp I deploy; I just do it, and after I can access them as a path like `loja-de-software.net.br/appOne` or `www.loja-de-software.net.br/appOne`.

Comment: So, if you can do that, then what is your problem?

Comment: I want deploy the webapp and access it as `loja-de-software.net.br` and not as `loja-de-software.net.br/appOne`. the RewriteRule suggested before do not acomplish this result.

Comment: And the current one?

Comment: Same result: access via `/appOne` only, `/` just list the directory. This works alongside the existing RewriteRule? I cannot remove those due it's essential to the https access (It was not me that put that there, but it was added automatically by the certification utilitary)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make one of the webapp available on the root context, you can rename the war file to ROOT.war and redeploy.
That used to work on tomcat8 at least...